# How to transform nested JSON to csv using jq

Tags: json, linux, csv, jq

I have tried to transform json in the following format to csv using jq on Linux cmd line, but with no success. Any help of guidance would be appreciated.

```
{
    "dir/file1.txt": [
      {
        "Setting": {
          "SettingA": "",
          "SettingB": null
        },
        "Rule": "Rulechecker.Rule15",
        "Description": "",
        "Line": 11,
        "Link": "www.sample.com",
        "Message": "Some message",
        "Severity": "error",
        "Span": [
          1,
          3
        ],
        "Match": "[id"
      },
      {
        "Setting": {
          "SettingA": "",
          "SettingB": null
        },
        "Check": "Rulechecker.Rule16",
        "Description": "",
        "Line": 27,
        "Link": "www.sample.com",
        "Message": "Fix the rule",
        "Severity": "error",
        "Span": [
          1,
          3
        ],
        "Match": "[id"
      }
    ],
    "dir/file2.txt": [
      {
        "Setting": {
          "SettingA": "",
          "SettingB": null
        },
        "Rule": "Rulechecker.Rule17",
        "Description": "",
        "Line": 51,
        "Link": "www.example.com",
        "Message": "Fix anoher 'rule'?",
        "Severity": "error",
        "Span": [
          1,
          18
        ],
        "Match": "[source,terminal]\n----\n"
      }
    ]
}
```

Ultimately, I want to present a matrix with **dir/file1.txt**, **dir/file2.txt** as rows on the left of the matrix, and all the keys to be presented as column headings, with the corresponding values.

```
| Filename  | SettingA | SettingB | Rule | More columns... |
| -------- | -------------- | -------------- | -------------- | -------------- |
| dir/file1.txt    |             | null | Rulechecker.Rule15 | |
| dir/file1.txt   |             | null | Rulechecker.Rule16 | |
| dir/file2.txt   |             | null | Rulechecker.Rule17  | |
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Iterate over the top-level key-value pairs obtained by `to_entries` to get access to the key names, then once again over its content array in `.value` to get the array items. Also note that newlines as present in the sample's last `.Match` value cannot be used as is in a line-oriented format such as CSV. Here, I chose to replace them with the literal string `\n` using `gsub`.

```bash
jq -r '
  to_entries[] | . as {$key} | .value[] | [$key,
    (.Setting | .SettingA, .SettingB),
    .Rule // .Check, .Description, .Line, .Link,
    .Message, .Severity, .Span[], .Match
    | strings |= gsub("\n"; "\\n")
  ] | @csv
'
```

```
"dir/file1.txt","",,"Rulechecker.Rule15","",11,"www.sample.com","Some message","error",1,3,"[id"
"dir/file1.txt","",,"Rulechecker.Rule16","",27,"www.sample.com","Fix the rule","error",1,3,"[id"
"dir/file2.txt","",,"Rulechecker.Rule17","",51,"www.example.com","Fix anoher 'rule'?","error",1,18,"[source,terminal]\n----\n"
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/2ttxAPnOzKk)

---

If you just want to dump all the values in the order they appear, you can simplify this by using `.. | scalars` to traverse the levels of the document:

```bash
jq -r '
  to_entries[] | . as {$key} | .value[] | [$key,
    (.. | scalars) | strings |= gsub("\n"; "\\n")
  ] | @csv
'
```

```
"dir/file1.txt","",,"Rulechecker.Rule15","",11,"www.sample.com","Some message","error",1,3,"[id"
"dir/file1.txt","",,"Rulechecker.Rule16","",27,"www.sample.com","Fix the rule","error",1,3,"[id"
"dir/file2.txt","",,"Rulechecker.Rule17","",51,"www.example.com","Fix anoher 'rule'?","error",1,18,"[source,terminal]\n----\n"
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/09gCLewD8Gj)

---

As for the column headings, for the first case I'd add them manually, as you spell out each value path anyways. For the latter case it will be a little complicated as not all coulmns have immediate names (what should the items of array `Span` be called?), and some seem to change (in the second record, column `Rule` is called `Check`). You could, however, stick to the names of the first record, and taking the deepest field name either as is or add the array indices. Something along these lines would do:

```bash
jq -r '
  to_entries[0].value[0] | ["Filename", (
    path(..|scalars) | .[.[[map(strings)|last]]|last:] | join(".")
  )] | @csv
'
```

```
"Filename","SettingA","SettingB","Rule","Description","Line","Link","Message","Severity","Span.0","Span.1","Match"
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/e9IHfaLRYBL)